# How do I get the values of the params from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to work with the inputs from a form before storing the records. I'm stuck at simply reading the params.

In my create controller, I have

```
def create
   @document_history = DocumentHistory.new(document_history_params)
   $temp1 = params[:by]
   $temp2 = params[:sent_to]
```

In my show, I have

```
<hr>
<%= $temp1 %>
<hr>
<%= $temp2 %>
```

On the show, $temp1 and $temp2 are blank. How can I read the params and store the value to a variable?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting global variables here.  What are you actually trying to do?  Do you redirect to the `@document_history` after creating it?  where do `params[:by]` and `params[:sent_to]` come from, can you post the form please.

Comment: I was only using the global variables as a debugging tool. The answer below got me going in the right direction. I just didn't fully understand how to get the parameter values and was missing the inclusion of the controller name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your fields are named in the standard rails way.That is,If your input fields are named like this `document_history[name]` then the correct way to access them would be `params[:document_history][:name]`.
To verify if they have been copied to your variable you can `print` to log.

Comment: I was missing the fact that I needed to include the controller name and not just the field name. That gets me going where i need to go.

Comment: @ChrisMendla it's the model name, not the controller name.  You can post to any controller e.g. `form_for DocumentHistory.new, url: foos_path`.  Now it goes to the foos controller, but the parameters would still be nested under `params[:document_history]`.